# Ariel Flesler scrollTo()

Tags: jquery, scrollto

Hi there I am trying to implement the scrollTo() by Ariel Flesler in a website but it seems that I am way too stupid to understand how to use it.

Here is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Penna 3d <!--da cambiare -->
         </title>
        <link href="assets/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dws-top">
            <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="#" alt="logo prodotto">
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#dws-slide" id="slide">Slide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#dws-teaser" id="teaser">Teaser</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#dws-explain" id="explain">Spiegazione</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#dws-info" id="info">info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#dws-footer" id="footer" >footer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dws-slide">

    </div>
    <div id="dws-teaser">

    </div>
    <div id="dws-explain">

    </div>
    <div id="dws-info">

    </div>
    <div id="dws-footer">
        <footer>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.superscrollorama.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/TweenMax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>
                $('#footer').on("click", function(){
                    $.scrollTo("#dws-footer");
                });
            </script>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

ok, if I click on the link nothing happend, I really tried everything (I think) but I really dont manage to make this plugin to work.

I've tried the animatescroll plugin as well, which is actually sidelly working, but if I click the second time on the same link it scroll back on its original position... 
can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vxx1echb/1/

What you need to do is include a `return false;` in your initialization method. The native div anchor href is overriding the scrollTo method. You can also change that link to just have an `href` of `#` (though it doesn't matter since `return false;` overrides it the default behavior anyways, but just to clarify you're not going to link via `href="#some-id"`).

Then you have to pass the scrollTo method the actual jQuery object you wanted it to scroll to, and a duration as the second argument, which in this case is `500` (milliseconds).

Comment: Thank you very much pizzasynthesis.